# Update keycloak from config file

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am using keycloak embedded into spring application explained in this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app

There is a configuration file for keycloak that is contained within that application, but the configuration is imported into keycloak and into database only the first time that application is started.

Is there a way to make updates on that config file reflect on the state of the keycloak?
Developers should be able to change configurations and push changes to version control. When somebody pulls the new configuration it should reflect on his local instance of keycloak.

Comment: A moderator seems to think that my answer is not a reasonable answer for stackoverflow... So, here again: This project might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/adorsys/keycloak-config-cli/